# How can I register generic decorator to consumers in rabbitmq masstransit using autofac?

Tags: rabbitmq, autofac, masstransit

The code below registers the consumer interface implementations and registers a generic decorator for generic consumer interface.

```
builder.AddMassTransit();

builder.Register
(
    context =>
    {
        var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {
            foreach (var messageConfiguration in messageConfigurations)
            {
                var type = messageConfiguration.Type; // MESSAGE TYPE

                if (messageConfiguration.Consumers.Any())
                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint($"{type.Namespace}:{type.Name}", ec =>
                    {
                        foreach (var cType in messageConfiguration.Consumers)
                            ec.ConfigureConsumer(context, cType);  //REGISTERS CONSUMER IMPLEMENTATION
                    });

            }
        });
        return busControl;
    }
)
.SingleInstance()
.As<IBusControl>()
.As<IBus>();




builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(typeof(ConsumerDecorator<>), typeof(IConsumer<>)); //DECORATES IConsumer interfaces.
```

Therefore a consumer implementation can be resolved without its decorator.

I need to register consumers as their interfaces instead of their implementations for resolving consumers with their decorators. So I can register a single generic consumer decorator using autofac.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to do that. But MT supports [Middlewares](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/) which is more correct way to do that.

Also, there is a sample: [Autofac_FilterSpecs.cs](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/e7f28cc09abae207f76c06b90c35d874f078e982/src/Containers/MassTransit.Containers.Tests/Autofac_FilterSpecs.cs)